# How to insert value in data base using sqlite in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Can you please tell me how to insert value in database. I just started development in android don't have much experience.

I just create one class `information` where I create getter and setter of name field.
package com.example.database_example;

```
package com.example.database_example;

public class Information {

    String name;
    public Information(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Now I create an another data base class where I want to add method of insert and read the data from data base.

```
package com.example.database_example;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseExample extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "information";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_Name= "Name";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

    public DataBaseExample(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String createTable= "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_Name+"("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + ")";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_Name);

            // Create tables again
            onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertname(Information information) {

        boolean createSuccessful = false;

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

      //  values.put(KEY_ID, information.getId());
        values.put(KEY_NAME, information.getName());

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        createSuccessful = db.insert(TABLE_Name, null, values) > 0;
        db.close();

        return createSuccessful;
    }

}
```

`Main File`

```
package com.example.database_example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Information inf=new Information("naveen");
        DataBaseExample dbx=new DataBaseExample(MainActivity.this);
        dbx.insertname(inf);
    }
```

`LogCat`

```
09-24 07:25:07.138: I/Database(392): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near ")": syntax error
09-24 07:25:07.138: E/Database(392): Failure 1 (near ")": syntax error) on 0x2a7080 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE Name(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,)'.
09-24 07:25:07.148: D/AndroidRuntime(392): Shutting down VM
09-24 07:25:07.148: W/dalvikvm(392): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.database_example/com.example.database_example.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error: CREATE TABLE Name(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error: CREATE TABLE Name(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1763)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.example.database_example.DataBaseExample.onCreate(DataBaseExample.java:34)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:126)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.example.database_example.DataBaseExample.insertname(DataBaseExample.java:55)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.example.database_example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
09-24 07:25:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  ... 11 more**
```

Answer (score 6):

Your android sqlite insert method could look like this:

```
public boolean create(Information information) {

    boolean createSuccessful = false;

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_NAME, information.getName());

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    createSuccessful = db.insert(tableName, null, values) > 0;
    db.close();

    return createSuccessful;
}
```

It can be added in your `DataBaseExample` class.

You can use it this way in your activity, or anywhere possible.

```
Information information = new Information(); 
information.setName("naveen"); 

if(new DataBaseExample().create(information)){
    Log.v(TAG, "save ok.");
}else{
    Log.v(TAG, "save failed.");
}
```

[See here](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/02/android-sqlite-tutorial.html) for more simple examples.

Comment: I think there is a sql querry on this function

Comment: No need for a raw sql query, db.insert() is the key.

Comment: but where is the value like if i want to insert value name ="naveen"

Comment: see my updated answer on how to user the created method and insert "naveen"

Comment: You also have to specify the `_id` since the primary key isn't autoincremented for his case.

Comment: ok..Sir please check my edit question .Till now I used autoincremented ID  .I will change so how to know that naveen is save in data base ,How to read value from data base

Comment: the method above returns true if the value was saved. see above. if you want to read the value, you can refer to the link i gave below.

Comment: you got extra comma: name TEXT,)

Comment: The link at the bottom of this post is broken as of January 26th 2015

Answer (score 4):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put("Messsage", msg);
values.put("Name", SenderName);
values.put("GroupName", Groupname);

db.insert("TableName", null, values);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first error is because of the extra comma you have put inside the `createTable` string after the last column definition `KEY_NAME+" TEXT,"`

```
String createTable= "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_Name+"("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + ")";
```

the correct form is as follow :

```
String createTable= "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_Name+"("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT"
            + ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code-

```
mSQLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase(); //To insert we need to writable //database. If database is not created/opened it will do the job.
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(key1,value1);
contentValues.put(key2,value2);
contentValues.put(key3,value3);
//...put the value for all the required colums of a row.....

long rowInserted = mSQLiteDatabase.insert(tablename,"",contentValues);
mSQLiteDatabase.close();//This is very important to close.Never forget this.
if(rowInserted != -1) {
//Insert success.
} else {
//Inser failed.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.hostelmangement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
public class DataBase  {
 DataBaseHelper database;
 int a=0;
 public DataBase(Context con)
         {

           database=new DataBaseHelper(con,"jojo", null,1);
         }
void insertData(String joindate, String name, String fathername, String dateofbirth, String housename, String houseplace, String housepin, String blood, String mobile, String email, String company, String companyplace, String companyphone, String companypin, String rent, String imgphoto, String imgproof)
{
    SQLiteDatabase sqld=database.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("join_date", joindate);
    cv.put("name", name);
    cv.put("father_name", fathername);      
    cv.put("date_of_birth", dateofbirth);                           
    cv.put("house_name", housename);
    cv.put("place", houseplace);
    cv.put("pin_no", housepin);
    cv.put("blood_group", blood);      
    cv.put("mobile", mobile);                           
    cv.put("email", email);
    cv.put("company", company);
    cv.put("company_place", companyplace);
    cv.put("company_phone", companyphone);
    cv.put("company_pin", companypin);      
    cv.put("rent", rent); 
    cv.put("pending",a+"");
    cv.put("status", "a");
    cv.put("photo",imgphoto); 
    cv.put("proof",imgproof); 
    sqld.insert("demo", null,cv);  
}
public List<User> getDetails()
{
    List<User> ar=new ArrayList<User>();
    SQLiteDatabase sqldg=database.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur=sqldg.rawQuery("select * from demo where status='a' order by name asc" , null);
    if(cur!=null)
    {
        if(cur.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                User user=new User();
                user.setId(cur.getInt(0));
                user.setJoindate(cur.getString(1));
                user.setName(cur.getString(2));
                user.setFathername(cur.getString(3));
                user.setDateofbirth(cur.getString(4));
                user.setHousename(cur.getString(5));
                user.setPlace(cur.getString(6));
                user.setPinno(cur.getString(7));
                user.setBloodgroup(cur.getString(8));
                user.setMobile(cur.getString(9));
                user.setEmail(cur.getString(10));
                user.setCompany(cur.getString(11));
                user.setCompanyplace(cur.getString(12));
                user.setCompanyphone(cur.getString(13));
                user.setCompanypin(cur.getString(14));
                user.setRent(cur.getString(15));
                user.setPhoto(cur.getString(18));
                user.setProof(cur.getString(19));
                ar.add(user);

            }
            while(cur.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    return ar;
}
public List<User> getDetailsforview(int memberid)
{
    List<User> ar=new ArrayList<User>();
    SQLiteDatabase sqldg=database.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur=sqldg.rawQuery("select * from demo where id="+memberid , null);
    if(cur!=null)
    {
        if(cur.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                User user=new User();
                user.setId(cur.getInt(0));
                user.setJoindate(cur.getString(1));
                user.setName(cur.getString(2));
                user.setFathername(cur.getString(3));
                user.setDateofbirth(cur.getString(4));
                user.setHousename(cur.getString(5));
                user.setPlace(cur.getString(6));
                user.setPinno(cur.getString(7));
                user.setBloodgroup(cur.getString(8));
                user.setMobile(cur.getString(9));
                user.setEmail(cur.getString(10));
                user.setCompany(cur.getString(11));
                user.setCompanyplace(cur.getString(12));
                user.setCompanyphone(cur.getString(13));
                user.setCompanypin(cur.getString(14));
                user.setRent(cur.getString(15));
                user.setPhoto(cur.getString(18));
                user.setProof(cur.getString(19));
                ar.add(user);

            }
            while(cur.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    return ar;
}
public List<User> getDateSort()
{
    List<User> ar=new ArrayList<User>();
    SQLiteDatabase sqldg=database.getReadableDatabase();
    //Cursor cur=sqldg.rawQuery("select * from demo order by join_date asc", null);
    Cursor cur=sqldg.rawQuery("select * from demo where status='a' order by name asc", null);
    if(cur!=null)
    {
        if(cur.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {

                User user=new User();
                user.setId(cur.getInt(0));
                String date=cur.getString(1);
                String date1=date.substring(8, 10);
                user.setJoindate(date1);
                user.setName(cur.getString(2));
                user.setFathername(cur.getString(3));
                user.setDateofbirth(cur.getString(4));
                user.setHousename(cur.getString(5));
                user.setPlace(cur.getString(6));
                user.setPinno(cur.getString(7));
                user.setBloodgroup(cur.getString(8));
                user.setMobile(cur.getString(9));
                user.setEmail(cur.getString(10));
                user.setCompany(cur.getString(11));
                user.setCompanyplace(cur.getString(12));
                user.setCompanyphone(cur.getString(13));
                user.setCompanypin(cur.getString(14));
                user.setRent(cur.getString(15));
                user.setPending(cur.getInt(16));
                user.setPhoto(cur.getString(18));
                user.setProof(cur.getString(19));
                ar.add(user);

            }
            while(cur.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    return ar;
}
public List<User> deactiveMembers() {

    List<User> ar=new ArrayList<User>();
    SQLiteDatabase sqldg=database.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur=sqldg.rawQuery("select * from demo where status='d' order by name asc", null);
    if(cur!=null)
    {
        if(cur.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                User user=new User();
                user.setId(cur.getInt(0));
                user.setJoindate(cur.getString(1));
                user.setName(cur.getString(2));
                user.setFathername(cur.getString(3));
                user.setDateofbirth(cur.getString(4));
                user.setHousename(cur.getString(5));
                user.setPlace(cur.getString(6));
                user.setPinno(cur.getString(7));
                user.setBloodgroup(cur.getString(8));
                user.setMobile(cur.getString(9));
                user.setEmail(cur.getString(10));
                user.setCompany(cur.getString(11));
                user.setCompanyplace(cur.getString(12));
                user.setCompanyphone(cur.getString(13));
                user.setCompanypin(cur.getString(14));
                user.setRent(cur.getString(15));
                user.setPhoto(cur.getString(18));
                user.setProof(cur.getString(19));
                ar.add(user);

            }
            while(cur.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    return ar;

}
public void Update(String joindate, String name, String fathername, String dateofbirth, String housename, String houseplace, String housepin, String blood, String mobile, String email, String company, String companyplace, String companyphone, String companypin, String rent, int id, String imgphoto, String imgproof)
{
    SQLiteDatabase sqld=database.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("join_date", joindate);
    cv.put("name", name);
    cv.put("father_name", fathername);      
    cv.put("date_of_birth", dateofbirth);                           
    cv.put("house_name", housename);
    cv.put("place", houseplace);
    cv.put("pin_no", housepin);
    cv.put("blood_group", blood);      
    cv.put("mobile", mobile);                           
    cv.put("email", email);
    cv.put("company", company);
    cv.put("company_place", companyplace);
    cv.put("company_phone", companyphone);
    cv.put("company_pin", companypin);      
    cv.put("rent", rent);
    cv.put("photo", imgphoto);
    cv.put("proof", imgproof);
    sqld.update("demo",cv,"id="+id, null);
}
public void pendinUpdate(int pending, int lastamount)
{
    SQLiteDatabase sqld=database.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("pending",lastamount);
    sqld.update("demo",cv,"id="+pending, null);
}
public void deleteUpdate(int id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase sqld=database.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("status","d");
    sqld.update("demo",cv,"id="+id, null);
}
public void activate(int id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase sqld=database.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("status","a");
    sqld.update("demo",cv,"id="+id, null);
}
```

}