# What is the most suitable way to import pre-created data to android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want my application to use manually created string data.
For example:

```
Title1 : Description1
Title2 : Description2
Title3 : Description3
```

There will be a long discription, such as termonology of smth.
And i want to import this data to my android app.
I read about some options, such as: SQLite, JSON.
But i cannot understand, how should i do this. Just move my `file.db` or `file.json` to assets folder or how ?

There are in my data maximum 100 terminologies with description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your json file like this:

```
[
{
    "Title": "Some title",
    "Description": "Some Description"
}, {
    "Title": "Some title1",
    "Description": "Some Description1"
}, {
    "Title": "Some title2",
    "Description": "Some Description2"
}, {
    "Title": "Some title3",
    "Description": "Some Description3"
}, {
    "Title": "Some title4",
    "Description": "Some Description4"
}
]
```

and store it in asset folder. On initial launch of your application you can check whether data is present in SQLite database or not if its not then you can [Parse JSON from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945411/android-java-how-can-i-parse-a-local-json-file-from-assets-folder-into-a-listvi).

Convert it into

`JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(jsonString);`

then you can add each title and description into the SQLitedatabase [Insert data into SQLITE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971434/how-to-insert-value-in-data-base-using-sqlite-in-android) by iterating over this JSONArray